# request for A to B or request to B for A?

Tags: prepositions

Seems like **request for A to B** is correct, based on my Google search. But is **request to B for A** also correct?

For example,

1. I requested for **the picture** to **John**
2. I requested to **John** for **the picture**

If the second form is wrong as it is, would it be correct if it is changed to "I sent a request to John for the picture?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing "request" in your title to "requested" in your examples, *both* versions are incorrect. They would have to be more like:

1. I requested the picture *from* John.
   (Note no "for").
2. I requested John for the picture.
   (This is clumsy English and not grammatical).

To use "request", you'd change them to:

1. I sent a request *for the picture* to John.
2. I sent a request *to John* for the picture.

These turn "request" into a noun: the request is the message asking for the picture. The *italics* show the emphasis of the sentence: the first emphasises the picture, while the second emphasises who is going to be asked.

You can also simply say "I will **ask** John for the picture."

Comment: Thanks. Which one do people mostly use?

Comment: The "sent a request" versions are more formal. Which one you'd use depends on the emphasis you want: if you're discussing how to get the picture, you'd use the first. If you're discussing who to ask, you'd use the second (I've added the emphasis above). But people would mostly use the less formal "ask" version

Comment: Do requested from and sent a request have different meaning?
I feel like they have different meaning. To me **I have just requested the picture from John** sounds like it is saying "I have just acquired the from picture from John" and **I have just sent a request for the picture to John** sounds like it is saying "I have just asked for the picture to John".

Comment: With both "I have just requested..." and "I have just sent a request...", you have (probably) not yet received the picture. The difference is more implied in the _form_ of the request. The first sounds more like a verbal request, while the second is written: e-mail, letter, text or other form that you'd "send". But you could use the first version for these too.